Can an ASP.NET Core Application Reference .NET Framework 4.8.1 DLLs?
Can an ASP.NET Core 8 application reference .NET Framework 4.8.1 Dlls?  Should it?
Our products are built on an n-tier architecture where business logic and other components are used by both desktop and web applications.  The desktop applications are essential to our product offering and we will always need them installed on customer PCs.
In our current development, we have everything using .NET 8 without issue. We are now facing a business decision to determine if we stay with .NET Core or go back to the older .NET Framework. The issue is cost. Even number versions of .NET Core have an end life of 3 years after its release date (e.g., .NET 8 will not be supported after November 2026 and the applications will need to be updated to .NET 10). Due to security and customer requirements, our applications would need to upgrade to the latest .NET Core every 3 years. This is fine for web applications because the server is only impacted and would take minimal time to upgrade to the latest version of software.
Upgrading the desktop applications every 3 years would take a lot of time and money. We have many customers with a large amount of PCs using our desktop applications.
Options
If we revert the business tier and components back to .NET Framework 4.8, can the ASP.NET Core web applications reference those .dlls without issue? If this is possible, is there a risk?
This development path would allow the desktop applications to be built with .NET Framework 4.8.1 and eliminate the 3 year upgrade required by .NET Core. It would also allow the web applications to stay in .NET Core.
The other option is to have all desktop and web applications return to the older .NET Framework.
I am reaching out for your insight towards this development/business decision that we are facing. Please keep in mind that there is no option to rewrite or eliminate the desktop application component of our product offering (It's a 20+ year old product).
I appreciate your time and effort on this question and look forward to your responses.
Thank you!

Upgrading the desktop applications every 3 years would take a lot of time and money. No it will not. It is literally a case of changing the TargetFramework version in each csproj and rebuilding. If you use Directory.Build.props, which you should be, then it is literally changing the TF in that single file. There is zero excuse to still be using .NET Framework in 2024.

After around 3.x version of .net-core you could no longer reference old .NET framework DLLs.   The goal of .net-core was to include all of the functionality of .net framework inside core, and that is mostly true.  (there are some small differences in implementation.)  It would be best to fully migrate to .NET core as future versions of Windows may not support older versions of .net framework.  With core you have the option to include the run-time so it will be independent from OS support.

The reason I mention the support of older versions of .net is because a long while back I remember it being a bit of a pain going from 2 to 3.x   Can't remember the exact details now, but it was a bear to deal with and still support the older OSes.   (this might have been back in win98/xp days...)

...and as long as you're upgrading, you can make the desktop app multi-platform by using Maui:  https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/maui  (hopefully it's fairly mature/stable now... never used it myself)
